# How to Remove element using react when a user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I have the following react code:

```
export class LoginButton extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <img id="logInButton" src="\assets\btn_google_signin_dark_focus_web@2x.png" onClick={() => { signIn() }}></img >
    );
}}
ReactDOM.render(<LoginButton />, document.getElementById('logInRoot'));
```

And HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="logInRoot"></div>
</body>
```

When the `signIn()` function is called, the google sign in UI from Firebase appears and the user logs in.

What I need to do is make the div with id "logInRoot" disappear. Then reappear if the user logs out again.

Here is my code for `signIn()`:

```
export const auth = getAuth();
export function signIn() {
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
        // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
    });
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I go about doing this?

Comment: This seems relevant: [How can I conditionally render elements with React and Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350261/how-can-i-conditionally-render-elements-with-react-and-firebase-via-map-function)